# find . -perm -u=w shows all files

Tags: find, file-permissions, centos6

I'm trying to find all files which have user write permission, but lack group write permission.  I can't get find to do what I want, however.  I backed down to just a simple example which still doesn't work:

find . -perm -u=w -exec ls -l {} \; | more

Instead of showing me only files for which user permissions include writeability, find seems to just be listing all the files, regardless of permission.  I've tried several variations that also fail:

find . -perm -u+w
find . -perm /u=w

All of them list all files instead of only ones writeable by owner.  I'm running Centos 6.8.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out; ls -l was listing the contents of "." as well as the individual files with write permission that I was wondering about.  Switching it to "ls -ld" shows just "." instead of all the files within the current directory, and gives the expected results.